# Tokbox Implementation - SNAPSHOT

Tags: opentok, tokbox

We are currently working on a Videoconferencing Project using Tokbox API. We have managed to work on the publisher and subscriber streams successfully but we are facing issues when we want to screengrab/snapshot the streams.

When we implement the codes provided by Tokbox, we can only successful save the initial stream (subscriber). We are not able to get the snapshot when we switch to a different subscriber.

We are managing the publisher and subscriber as separate DIV. We have included the doubleclick event to maximise the subscriber stream from a thumbnail size.

Hope someone can assist us on this issue.

Comment: Can you provide some example code that shows the issue? It's hard to tell from this description what could be going wrong.

Comment: Issue has been fixed. Thanks for the time taken to reply.